# SQL Server limit ALTER permissions

Tags: sql-server, database-permissions

I've implemented a process to import data to a database that needs to set `IDENTITY_INSERT ON` and `OFF`.

However, to have this permission the user must own the table or have `ALTER` permission on the table.

As changing the process is not possible, my question is if it is possible to limit the grants given to a user when giving him the `ALTER` permission.

i.e., at the end of the day I would like to have an user with `ALTER` permission that can set `IDENTITY_INSERT ON` and `OFF` but CANNOT add/remove columns nor similar stuff.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you replace the `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` statements with something else, like a stored procedure call?

Comment: Can you encapsulate the import process in a stored proc? If so, you could use module signing with a certificate user with the needed permissions. The invoking user would only need permissions to execute on the proc.

Comment: @DanGuzman: this should probably be a question on its own, but is there any reason (security or otherwise) to prefer the certificate hoopla over simply creating a separate user `WITHOUT LOGIN`, `GRANT ALTER` to that, and using `EXECUTE AS` on the sproc?

Comment: @JeroenMostert, Erland Sommarskog discusses these considerations in his thorough article on the subject: http://www.sommarskog.se/grantperm.html. I agree certs are a little more work but more flexible and robust.

Comment: @DanGuzman: I've actually read Erland's article (well, all of them, actually); the main problem with certificates is the odious requirement for re-signing after every change, which I haven't yet found to outweigh the "more flexible and robust" advantages (they are only *really* necessary if you require the original user's identity be used for operations). Yes, you can solve that with even more plumbing, but if all you need to do is grant *one* particular permission for *one* app... ...that said, this is going off topic since there's not even an answer yet. :-)